# Display array result in marquee tag like news ticker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to display result of my ajax query in marquee tag like news ticker.
Unfortunately i am not able to display content inside the array.

JavaScript Code:

```
                success: function (data) {
                var NewsList= [];
                  for (var i = 0 ; i< data.query.table.length; i++) {
                       NewsList[i] = data.query.table[i];

                    };
                      $scope.news = NewsList;

         },
```

Html Code:

```
<div ng-controller ="newsController"><!-- ng-controller ="newsController" -->
    <marquee ng-repeat="new in news">{{new}}</marquee>
```

Output in chrome console log:

```
[Array[1],Array[1],Array[1],.....]
```

Output inside array looks like Array[391]->Array[0-99]->0:Array[1]->0:"hellowolrd". and so on.

May be i have to iterate through arrays but unfortunately i am not able to do so.I am using ng - repeat angularjs. Can team help me with above query.
Thank You.

Json result in browser console

```
{"query":{"resultCode":0,"columns":["tnps_global_rating_reason_comment"],"table":[[""],["Im using a vodafone since 2010 to 2014 and from july 2016 up to now"],["Abhi bohot jaldi hai"],["سرعه الخدمه وجودتها"],["0"],[""],["خدمه عملاء جيده جدا وتم حل مشكلتي"],["2"]]}}
```

Comment: can u show the `data.query.table` json

Comment: is `data.query.table` object array or 2 dimensional  array

Comment: hello i have amended the question with json result.

Comment: i want to fetch result inside table array in above json output to display in marquee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple do this,

```
  <marquee ng-repeat="eachnew in news.query.table">{{eachnew}}</marquee>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("newsController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.news  = 
      {"query":{"resultCode":0,"columns":["tnps_global_rating_reason_comment"],"table":[[""],["Im using a vodafone since 2010 to 2014 and from july 2016 up to now"],["Abhi bohot jaldi hai"],["سرعه الخدمه وجودتها"],["0"],[""],["خدمه عملاء جيده جدا وتم حل مشكلتي"],["2"]]}};
  
 } 
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="newsController">          
    <marquee ng-repeat="eachnew in news.query.table">{{eachnew}}</marquee>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Below is console output:

Comment: Object
query
:
Object
columns
:
Array[1]
0
:
"tnps_global_rating_reason_comment"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
resultCode
:
0
table
:
Array[463]
[0 … 99]
0
:
Array[1]
0
:
"Ushar"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
1
:
Array[1]

Comment: I want to fetch value -> 0 : "Ushar" from above objects.

Comment: @user2646207 there is no value named ushar with the json you posted